# How do I change the android actionbar title with tab menu?

Tags: android

How do I change the android actionbar title when i select tab menu?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your **onPageSelected()** , try following code,

```
 getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Title");;
```

This may helps you.